# Multiple relations between two tables (User and Product)

Tags: database

Is it acceptable database design to have two different relations between two table. 
For instance, the user can create a product and buy the product. 
So there will be relation between the user and the product one to many where the product table has the UserId, while when the user buys a product it is a many to many relation which is created by joint table that has UserId and ProductId that represents the order.

It is a good design or there is another way of doing that ?

Comment: I would also design it like that. A product has exactly one "owner" or "creator", therefore put the reference into the product table. Who buys what is an m:n, therefore create a relation table. You still can join the product table with multiple records of the user table.

Comment: Will that be a loop relations between the three tables ?

Comment: no. you would have a query like
`select u1.name as owner_name, p.title as product, u2.name as buyer_name
from user as u1, product as p, purchase as pur, user as u2
where u1.id = p.owner_id
and pur.product_id = p.id
and u2.id = pur.buyer_id
;` 
it's only that you have one table joined twice, but no recursion

Comment: That makes sense. Then it will be two different relations between two tables. thanks.